# Are you a cry(ing) baby?

Tags: questions, progressive-aspect, idiomatic-language

Someone is not crying at the moment, but you want to ask if that person's character is more like it so, how would you ask?

1. Are you a crying baby?
2. Are you a cry baby?

Comment: _Crybaby_ is a noun with a specific meaning. _Cry baby_ is without meaning in English..

Answer (score 1):

A "crying baby" is a literal phrase meaning a baby -- a person from newborn to perhaps a year old or so -- who is presently crying.

A "crybaby" is a term used to insult someone. It means someone who gets upset too easily, especially for not getting something they want. For example, if a group of friends decided to go to lunch together and they took a vote where to go, and someone who lost the vote then said, "Oh, I hate that place. Can't we go someplace else?" and went on and on complaining that he didn't like the group's choice, someone might say, "Oh, don't be such a crybaby. We can go someplace you like next time."

It's hard to imagine when you would ask someone, "Are you a crying baby?" Anyone who IS a crying baby is too young to talk and thus could not answer, so the only sensible answer would be a puzzled, "Umm, no, of course not."

You would only ask someone, "Are you a crybaby?" rhetorically, that is, meaning, "You are a crybaby". It would be a slightly milder form of the insult.